# C++ Memory Limit Exceeded when running small numbers

Tags: c++

I am making a code for a problem on [Iceland.Kattis.Com called voff](https://iceland.kattis.com/problems/iceland.voff) in which you have to calculate the number of dogs required to produce a certain frequency of barks.

There are N barks and each dog can bark up to once every K seconds. The first line of input contains N and K, the second line contains the times at which barks were heard.

I have made a python code which is almost fast enough to get 100 points but just a little bit shy of getting there. So I decided to write the same code but in C++ (clang 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1) and when I run any other test case than the first one I get Memeory Limit Exceeded.

I have tried using 'long long', 'unsigned long long' and 'int' but I get Memory Limit Exceeded on all of them.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  int N, K;
  vector<int> barks;
  vector<int> dogs;
  dogs.push_back(0);

  cin >> N >> K;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    int inp;
    cin >> inp;
    barks.push_back(inp);
  }


  for(int bark : barks){
    for(int i = 0; i < dogs.size(); i++){
      if (bark >= dogs[i]){
        dogs[i] = bark + K;
        break;
      } else {
        dogs.push_back(bark + K);
      }
    }
  }
  cout << dogs.size() << endl;
}
```

When inputting the first test case the output is and should be '1'.
But when running any other test case the it Exceeds the Memory Limit.

Comment: What are the inputs, for which you exceed the memory limit? What are those memory limits?

Comment: Also what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: You're adding to the `dogs` vector whilst iterating over it. If your `if (bark >= dogs[i])` statement is always `false` (which is fairly easy to do) then you'll add to the dogs vector once per loop and therefore never get to the end of the `dogs` vector.

Comment: I'm guessing your python code did this instead `size_t s = dogs.size(); for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){` and you've just ported it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up with an infinite number of dogs as each dog you add in the `for i` loop fails the `bark >= dogs[i]` test which causes another dog to be added and so on.

Changing your code to only add one dog when no dogs match the condition works:

```
for (int bark : barks) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dogs.size(); i++) {
        if (bark >= dogs[i]) {
            dogs[i] = bark + K;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        dogs.push_back(bark + K);
    }
}
```

P.S. don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, it is non standard and only works on some platforms, include just the c++ headers you need (e.g. `<iostream>` and `<vector>`) instead. `using namespace std` can also cause issues.

Comment: I am using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` since I was writing this in a competitive programming contest and I don't have a lot of time to find out what includes I need and it's just faster for me to use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` if I had written the code not in a competitive programming contest I would have used `<iostream>`and `<vector>`in place for `<bits/stdc++.h>`.